# divide routes in Open Street Maps on certain length

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

I am never was working with any Map SDK. Now I am going to develop a Map based application.
I would like use OpenStreetMap for this development. The are 2 main questions which I was trying to get answer:
!. Is it possible to divide a route on parts of certain distance? Let say generated route is about 1500 miles. I would like to divide it (get coordinates) on segments of 500 miles each.
2. Is it possible to divide each part  on tails of predefined length and width?
I appreciate any help